# All validations firing simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm not sure if this is just me being new to validators in ASP or not, but I have a sign up page with multiple required fields that each have a RequiredFieldValidator, as well as a few other validations. If the user doesn't enter the first required field, all my validations fire and all my error messages show up. There has to be a way to make it so only the validation for the text box the user is on show up? If the user is on the first of 5 text boxes let's say, I don't want all the validations for all 5 text boxes pop up after the user fails the first text box for example.

On that note, is there anyway to make a validation or a validation summary to show up after clicking a button? I have a validation summary right now but like my validators, it immediately fires if the user fails one validation. I was looking at this example and this is how I want my validation summary to behave, but I can't seem to figure out how they are doing it in their code: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_validationsum

Comment: Classic ASP had no concept of validators. You must be talking about ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using validation summary, make use of ValidatorCalloutExtender control which is available in ajax control toolkit.

You just need to place separate ValidatorCalloutExtender control for each validation control you have in your page and set TargetControlID property of ValidatorCalloutExtender to the ID of validation control.

This will display error message of validation control in callout popup. You will have to set display property of validation control to "none".

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript alert or prompt message for validation.It will be shown for each field separatedly.